# I want to create a Morse code converter

Tags: c

In my project's school I need to convert a word into Morse code.

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
for (letter = 0; letter > 1000; letter ++)
    {
        scanf ("%s", &word [letter]);

        if (word [letter] == 'a') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '.-';

        if (word [letter] == 'b') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '-...';

        if (word [letter] == 'c') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '-.-.';

        if (word [letter] == 'd') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '-..';

        if (word [letter] == 'e') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '.';

        if (word [letter] == 'f') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '..-.';

        if (word [letter] == 'g') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '--.';

        if (word [letter] == 'h') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '....';

        if (word [letter] == 'i') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '..';

        if (word [letter] == 'j') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '.---';

        if (word [letter] == 'k') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '-.-';

        if (word [letter] == 'l') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '.-..';

        if (word [letter] == 'm') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '--';

        if (word [letter] == 'n') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '-.';

        if (word [letter] == 'o') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '---';

        if (word [letter] == 'p') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '.--.';

        if (word [letter] == 'q') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '--.-';

        if (word [letter] == 'r') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '.-.';

        if (word [letter] == 's') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '...';

        if (word [letter] == 't') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '-';

        if (word [letter] == 'u') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '..-';

        if (word [letter] == 'v') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '...-';

        if (word [letter] == 'w') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '.--';

        if (word [letter] == 'x') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '-..-';

        if (word [letter] == 'y') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '-.--';

        if (word [letter] == 'z') wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '--..';

        printf ("%s", &wordInMorse [letter]);
   }
```

After running the program and writting a word, it crashes and in the Build messages tab, every line with `if (word [letter] == '/*letter*/' wordInMorse [4 * letter] = '/*morse*/';`) says that "overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]" and "multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]".

Comment: Interesting for loop you have there: it will never execute.

Comment: You need to post more of your code than just this.

Comment: By the way, a character constant is exactly ONE character. So `'.---'` is invalid. Maybe you mean a string?

Comment: Try making the program as small as possible, with only one letter and a default (in case some one annoying puts a "^" in scanf..... Then you can start debugging. The comments above already say to use " instead of ' for strings. You didn't define `word` but it seems you're using it like an allocated array of char*. That needs more allocation.

Answer (score 1):

To guide you, without making your homework, you could take the following approach:

- Make `wordInMorse` a global array of 26 pointers to strings.
- Initialize this array with strings that are the letters in Morse code, so the first element of `wordInMorse` points to the Morse code for the letter A (or a). Can you do this with initializers or do you need code to do this in your main program?
- in your main program, when the user enters a string, lookup each letter in this array and print the string with the Morse code.

To convert a letter of the input to an index in the array, make the letter uppercase and subtract `'A'`.

Good luck!

Comment: To be honest I haven't learnt how to make pointers nor strings yet, this is part of my final project and I didn't know that I needed pointers to make it. I'll learn that in the next class, thanks anyway.